# iPhone development on Windows

Tags: iphone, windows, ios

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I develop for iPhone using a Windows development machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22358/how-can-i-develop-for-iphone-using-a-windows-development-machine)

Is there a way to develop iPhone (iOS) applications on Windows?  I really don't want to get yet another machine.

There is a project on http://code.google.com/p/winchain/wiki/HowToUse that seemed to work with iPhone 1.0, but had limited success with iPhone 2.0, plus it requires all the [Cygwin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cygwin) insanity.

Is there anything else, or do I have to buy a Mac?