# Possible (as of October 2010) to develop an iPhone app on a Windows 7?

Tags: iphone, windows-7

First off I know this has been covered on SO.  But the most popular posts I see date back to:

- September 2008 - [iPhone development on
  Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/113547/iphone-development-on-windows) (over 2 years ago)
- February 2009 - [The iPhone and a PC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/573986/the-iphone-and-a-pc) (1 year 8 months ago)

Have there been any developments on this issue since these posts?  Am I still just better off trying to find a reasonably priced mac on craigslist?  Is there a mac emulator that I could run on my Windows 7 machine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as far as I know, it is not possible, at least not smoothly as you wish.

Apple will never support it, as they will never support two hardware platforms and two operating systems. More than that, they will not be able to guarantee the experience and quality of running stuff at the same level that it is on a Mac.

Another point is that they want you to use their hardware, because they know the moment you use it, you will never use Windows again (trust me, I see that happening to every single person that crossed that bridge). The experience is far superior. (you will never switch back to a VW Beetle after starting driving a Ferrari)

Obviously you will always have solutions for running stuff on Windows and make it work, but your environment will be too adapted that I don't recommend this. C'mon, for about $500 you can buy a 2008 iMac. It is not that much money.

Comment: `...the moment you use it, you will never use Windows again` I've used my mom's mac before.  It confuses and frightens me...

Comment: @Abe, I use both comfortably. The learning curve is not very steep. I am even able to switch between using COMMAND- (Mac) shortcuts and CTRL- (Windows) shortcuts interchangeably.

Comment: @Abe: If the thought of using a desktop Mac scares you, what hope do you have of developing for iOS? I know you were being facetious, but be honest to yourself: if you're not willing to invest the time and effort into learning to cope with a new OS and development environment, any applications you develop are likely to be subpar. Would you want to develop for Windows Mobile from OS X?

Comment: @Sedate, I was being facetious and I do see your point.  I just hate having to drop the money when I have such a nice development machine at home but I guess that's the way it goes...

Comment: wait to say that a year after using a Mac... :-)

Comment: ha, we will see @Digital. If i don't love it I'm going to come looking for you ;)

Answer (score 0):

If time is money, and you don't want to spend your time fighting with immature development tools with various limitations (especially support), then for iOS app development you should get at least a used or refurb Mac Mini (with an Intel CPU + Snow Leopard).

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, t run Mac OS X on certain pc hardware. But as it not allowed by apple, and it is somewhat painfully to set it up, considering buying a mac to develop for iphone, is the best choice. The risky side however is, that you may start hateing Objective-C and that you will have wasted money on buying a Mac ;-)

Alternativly for small prupose apps, considering developing apps with the help of html5, css and javascript could be a choice. Later you can "deploy" the app over safari, by adding the site (app) to your homescreen.