# Can I develop iPhone applications using C#.NET on Vista?

Tags: c#, iphone, mobile

I’m interested in developing an iPhone application using Visual Studio and C#.NET on Windows Vista.

I tried to download the SDK from http://developer.apple.com/iphone/index.action, but the file has a `.dmg` extension and I don’t know how to open that file.

So can I as .NET developer work and develop against iPhone APIs?
And are there any existing applications which haven been developed using .NET?
Are there any resources or web sites can help in that matter?

Thanks!

Comment: The accepted answer doesn't take Xamarin into account which has been released recently. See tomfanning's answer.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In a word, no. There is Mono support for the iPhone, but it's currently limited. They have spoken in the past about the possibility of writing a Silverlight app, with a series of "iPhone style" controls that could be statically linked as an iPhone app, but that's some way off.

If it's games you're interested in, and you have deep pockets, then [UNITY](http://unity3d.com/unity/features/iphone-publishing) is a Mono based game development platform that supports the iPhone (and runs on Windows)

Failing that, bite the bullet and get a cheap Mac from EBay. Officially only Intel Macs are supported for the SDK, but you can get it to install on PPC ones and I've yet to have a problem with that (I'm running it on a G5 PowerMac at the moment)

Answer (score 10):

**UPDATE 7/18/2013:**

Since this answer is 3 years old I would like to update it with current information. MonoTouch is no more because it is now part of [Xamarin](http://www.xamarin.com). With it you can develop mobile applications using C# and parts of the .NET Framework (using Mono). [You can develop iOS apps using Windows](https://store.xamarin.com/) and Visual Studio, but you still need a Mac to compile and build. [Here's](http://blog.xamarin.com/introduction-to-building-xamarin.ios-applications-in-visual-studio/?mkt_tok=3RkMMJWWfF9wsRonv6TNZKXonjHpfsXw6OgkT/rn28M3109ad%2brmPBy%2b3oUJWp8na%2bqWCgseOrQ8mVsNV8q6RM0XrKw=) a blog post on how to use VS for iOS development.

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

[MonoTouch](http://monotouch.net/). You still need a mac and a minimum of $400 (as of this writing)

You can try the eval version which doesn't require you to pay and allows you program using the simulator. If you want to test your app on the hardware then you need to pocket the money.

Comment: Be interesting to see how this plays out: http://techcrunch.com/2010/04/08/adobe-flash-apple-sdk/

Comment: According to Miguel de Icaza, this doesn't affect MonoTouch. There have been plenty of apps approved in the iPhone SDK since the new agreement

Answer (score 3):

No, you cannot.

Comment: so how i can develop iPhone application?

Answer (score 3):

yes. monotouch works fine

Answer (score 3):

Current answer to this question is yes, with MonoTouch from Novell using MonoDevelop on a Mac computer, but bear in mind that Novell laid off the Mono/MonoTouch guys, who are right now in the middle of setting up a startup to replace MonoTouch with a new product called Xamarin, due for release this summer.

**January 2013**

Xamarin came through with MonoTouch and Mono for Android quite a while ago now, both of which are great products, if somewhat expensive for the enthusiast.

Answer (score 2):

This [similar question asks if iPhone development is possible on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/113547/iphone-development-on-windows).

The answer appears to be: only for [Jailbroken](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jailbreak_(iPhone)) iPhones.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to develop for the iPhone in C# using  [Unity](http://unity3d.com/unity/features/iphone-publishing). It performs ahead of time compilation as described [here](http://tirania.org/blog/archive/2008/Nov-05.html).
However, Unity seems more aimed at developing games and the iPhone SDK currently  requires Mac OSX.

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot.

The .dmg extension stands for "disk image" and is used for installation files in Mac OS X. Windows Vista won't understand the format and hence you cannot open it.

Also, you won't get the libraries/SDK needed for developing iPhone apps in a .NET framework. You will have to download the latest version of iPhone SDK which comes with an iPhone emulator for testing on the development machine. The main framework used for iPhone development is the UIKit.

The best place to start learning about iPhone development is [here](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ApplicationEnvironment/ApplicationEnvironment.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH7-SW1).

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, no, you cannot develop standard iPhone apps with C#/.NET.

However, I've seen screenshots of mono running on an iPhone, so, someday perhaps ... although, it probably won't be in a legal setup.

Answer (score 1):

The iPhone does not support .NET.  I don't believe there are any compatibility hacks or anything like that to run .NET apps on an iPhone, so you might have to bite the bullet and learn Objective-C.

I would do a google search for "iPhone development tutorials."  There will probably be a bit of a learning curve.

Comment: Unfortunately, there isn't a great iPhone IDE on windows.  There are supposedly Eclipse/Aptana plugins for iPhone dev, but I'm not sure.  You might be best off looking for a cheap Mac to do iPhone dev.

Answer (score 1):

or you could just run mac os on your pc
http://oreilly.com/windows/archive/PearPC.html
check it out

Answer (score 1):

MonoTouch runs on Mac..  For windows you can look at DragonFireSDK.  Currently for game development, it allows developing iPhone applications in Visual Studio 2010 using C++ .Net.

http://www.dragonfiresdk.com