# Program iPhone Applications in Windows?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Is it possible? From what I have heard it is. I wouldn't mind just programming them in raw Objective-C. If someone could give a link to the UIKit frameworks and stuff. My iPod touch is jailbroken and I could use its frameworks, but then I couldn't utilize 3G, Camera, Phone. Please help!

Comment: Lots and lots of duplicates.  Here's one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/113547/iphone-development-on-windows

Comment: I could program the app and then compile it on my iPod touch. Can someone post a tutorial on how to make the nib and plist and other files?

Comment: you cannot compile on the touch.  The iPod does not support development

Comment: I can. I have a jailbroken iPod touch on 3.1.2 and in cydia there are development tool to compile in mobileterminal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the answers to [113547](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/113547/iphone-development-on-windows)

Answer (score 0):

only if your copy of windows is running on a mac… and you bypass the windows part of it.

Answer (score 0):

the short answer will be NO.

However, it is possible to implement parts of your Iphone application on Windows. Start by installing GNUstep, after that you should be able to code in Objective-C.

Take as example a small two-dimensional game implementation, you can implement on your Windows machine 90% of the app (game AI, help functions etc.). If you use OpenGL ES for the graphical part you can code parts of it on Windows too.

You can find a concise introduction on how to start with Objective-C on Windows on this blog:

http://drunkenprogrammerblog.blogspot.com/

Best wishes