# What is minimum hardware and software requirements for Iphone native apps development?

Tags: iphone, ios-simulator

Can i develop and test iphone native applications on windows pc and testing in any iphone simulator? If no then, What is minimum hardware and software requirements for Iphone native apps development. I want to make development environment setup in minimum possible price.

Comment: This is a duplicate of many, many questions here, including the following: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/113547/iphone-development-on-windows, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/190662/whats-the-cheapest-mac-development-box-possible

Answer (score 10, accepted):

- Intel-based Mac (can be a Mac Mini; I prefer a MacBook Pro that I can take with me and develop in a variety of locations, office, a playground while kids play, when I travel...)
- Xcode (free download)

Optional software I use all the time:

- Adobe Photoshop (or similar bitmap
  and/or vector based image editing
  software)
- Logic Pro (or similar sound editing software with a library of
  sfx)

The optional stuff is not something I needed as much for other software development.  It seems that on the iPhone, the audio/visual experience is as much a selling point as the functionality of the app.

As for whether a simulator is good enough, I have to say NO!  The iPhone Simulator is adequate for simple apps, but it operates at a faster processing speed than iPhones and iPhone Touches, making your app run faster than it would in the real world.  It also behaves differently in a number of ways, which makes it important to have a 'real' alternative.  In fact, during a day of development, I may use the iPhone Simulator for 80% of the test builds, and an iPhone OS device for the other 20% in order to make sure I am on the right track.  I have two iPhones with 3.0 and 2.0 software, plus two iPod Touches.  The 2.0 iPhone is the 3G, which is the slowest, then the iPod Touches are a bit faster, and the iPhone 3Gs is the fastest of the bunch.  I test with all to make sure the user experience doesn't get too sluggish on the slowest.

Comment: One problem in MAC if i buy MAC for iphone development then i cannot do Windows mobile development.

Comment: Stop doing Windows mobile development. Simple.

(Did you know you can run Windows on a Mac?  It is Mac not MAC)

Seriously, if you are a professional developer, then you shouldn't be solving problems based on what the least common denominator is. If this is just a hobby, then I can see how you might want to skimp.  

As mentioned above, if you have to minimize expenditure, you could run MacOS on a Windows or Linux machine, but you'll find a lot of us who haven't tried it and wouldn't be able to answer your questions if you have issues.

Comment: @jitendra, anyway - buy a mac, and dual-boot it with windows (using bootcamp) and do both. running osx on a windows based machine is just overkill for ios development.

Answer (score 4):

You basically need an Intel-based Mac. You can find used Mac mini's for cheap (and use an existing monitor and USB keyboard/mouse).

Comment: Yeah. I use the cheapest Mac Mini with the RAM and hard drive it came with. No problem.

Comment: ok and what about testing on iphone. do i need to purchase iphone or any simulator can do all testing?

Comment: or can i purchase and install Mac OSX and on my current Windows XP Intel machine or it is necassary to purchase Mac Mini?

Comment: You need a device. A touch or an iphone.

Comment: You will want to test on a device. iPod Touches are cheapest. If your users will be using your app on 3G a lot though or GPS, then you will probably want to get yourself an iPhone. This has the added benefit of joining the community you will be developing for.

Comment: Some people have installed Mac OS X on PCs ("Hackintosh") and some people have done some iPhone development on PCs (probably Linux, not sure about Windows). The general consensus of both (especially the latter) is that it is NOT worth the effort.

Comment: to install Mac OS X on PC is legal ?

Comment: It probably breaks the license agreement.

Comment: It isn't approved to install MacOS on non-Apple hardware.  However, I would hate to chase after a development issue or bug, and wonder if it is my underlying hardware that is the problem or something I am doing.  The piece of mind from running an approved system is worth the $1000 for a Mac-based system (+/-$ based on configuration).

Comment: which macbook(laptop) is enough for development?

Comment: So there is not good simulator to test Iphone applications. purcahse iphone will be the best

Comment: Well yes and no. The simulator provided is good, but runs faster than an iphone and doesn't perfectly behave like an iphone (though it's pretty close). It's just not enough to develop on a simulation...

Comment: Remember the simulator is on the screen. The iPhone is a multitouch, accelerometer, gps device. The simulator is good to get started with, but a lot of apps quickly move to the "must-test-on-device" stage. And the simulator and the device run on different processors. They don't even have all the same bugs when you're coding. Device testing is mandatory.

Answer (score 2):

If you're serious about iPhone development, buy a refurbished Mac Mini and a refurbished iPhone to test it on. If you just want to play around first, search Stack Overflow for the thousand other questions that answer how to do iPhone development on windows.

Answer (score 0):

If you're serious about iPhone development, buy a refurbished Mac Mini and a refurbished iPhone to test it on.I prefer to use mac-Mini or an intel based mac.You can do almost all testing on Simulator except these few which requires original hardware(Gps,Opening another iPhone app from your native app).In terms of memory simulator doesn't have it's own memory it depends on your hardware memory so if you want to develop a good bug free app go purchase an iPhone.