# System Requirement for iPhone development 

Tags: iphone, ios4

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is minimum hardware and software requirements for Iphone native apps development?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777981/what-is-minimum-hardware-and-software-requirements-for-iphone-native-apps-develop)

Hi, im planning to buy a apple development machine for iphone development im completly new to this platform please any one can tell me what are the minimum configuration of mac machine for iphone developent in which i can easily install latest iphone sdk and xcode and all the stuff which are required for iphone application development.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Any Intel-based Mac with Snow Leopard will do.

Comment: can you tell me how much gb ram is enough,

Comment: I think that it is 1gb for the latest xcode but I'd recommend 2gb

Comment: +1 Anything less than 2Gb and you're going to suffer.

Answer (score 2):

Via http://developer.apple.com/support/ios/ios-dev-center.html:

> **What are the system requirements for the iOS SDK?**
>
> To develop with iOS SDK and
>   participate in the iOS Developer
>   Program you must have an Intel-based
>   Mac running Mac OS X Snow Leopard.
>   Refer to the iOS SDK Read Me document
>   for full details on system
>   requirements. You must be registered
>   as an Apple Developer in order to
>   access the iOS SDK and iOS SDK Read Me
>   document.

Answer (score 1):

Buy mac with much more RAM. I bought mac mini with 2gb and sometimes xcode have lag.