# What is the minimum OpenGL version required for developing on iOS 8?

Tags: ios, macos, opengl, vmware

Since I can't afford a Mac, I learned so far that the maximum supported OpenGL version in VMware Workstation 10 on a guest is 2.1. And yes, my plan is to virtualize Mac OS from a Ubuntu Host.

To be honest I don't want to use any Hackintosh since it will mean a lot of time-consuming reconfiguration, with also the loss of my long-lasting laptop ability with optimus/bumblebee.

The problem is that I haven't found any data about this for iOS 8, or any news about a higher supported OpenGL version in VMWare Workstation. Furthermore, OpenGL 2.1 is supported on Workstation since 7.5, so this information should be very outdated.

Although, any information about the previous IOS simulator's (7, 6, 5 and 4) OpenGL (at OS X level) requirements are also very welcomed (they are my backup solutions), same thing for VMware Workstation guests' maximum supported openGL version.

I've checked a "similar" post, but found nothing that is up to date too: [What is minimum hardware and software requirements for Iphone native apps development?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777981/what-is-minimum-hardware-and-software-requirements-for-iphone-native-apps-develo)

Comment: Are you asking about the OpenGL ES versions that iOS uses or the OpenGL versions that OS X supports?

Comment: I'm asking about the OpenGL version that OS X must support in order to correctly run the iOS 8 emulator.

Comment: That's not really how OS X works, to be honest. It's not like Windows or Linux where the version the platform supports is dictated by some hardware (or software) drive you install after the fact. On OS X, your supported OpenGL version is set in stone by Apple when they publish the operating system, because they write the one and only OpenGL implementation (a surprisingly efficient  and full-featured software implementation, plus various hardware implementations for Intel, AMD and NV GPUs). I would suggest looking [here](https://developer.apple.com/opengl/capabilities/).

Comment: Oh, that's something that I didn't found on the net, thanks :D. By the way, does it really means that if OS X is released to support OpenGL 3.2, can I still use it's instructions even if my hardware only supports OpenGL 2.1 ? I mean, like the GPUs way of supporting the latest OpenGL (4.5) trough drivers even if they were designed physically for a very older one ? (Like the Fermi 400 series was designed for 4.0 but now supports 4.5)

Comment: @user3755746: Yes, if you are able to run a version of OS X on your machine that supports OpenGL 3.2, you will be able to use OpenGL 3.2 regardless what GPU you have installed. But, and this is a *huge* but on OS X, it will fallback to much slower software for anything the GPU doesn't support. That sort of thing very rarely happens in Windows/Linux; if your hardware doesn't support something on other platforms, you usually don't get that feature at all.

Answer (score 0):

Developing on a VM is not a good idea. If you want to learn on VM and mess around, that's ok. But otherwise you're going to run into a lot of other problems later on. However, if you install bare MacOS on your PC, that would be okay. See: http://www.macbreaker.com/2014/01/install-osx-mavericks-on-pc-with-niresh.html

The only difficulty with this solution is that your PC hardware may or may not be compatible with a bare MacOS installation ("Hackintosh").

Comment: If you're going to tell someone something is not a good idea make sure to back it up with reasons why, simply saying `you're going to run into a lot of other problems later on` is not particularly helpful. This also doesn't answer the question.