# Is C# the same as Objective-C?

Tags: c#, objective-c, programming-languages

Simple question, I'm just looking for a yes or no clarification. A citation would be appreciated but not necessary.

Bonus Question - Can Objective-C be used on Windows, or only on Mac OS?

Comment: Please post your "bonus question" as a separate question.

Comment: Adam - It's a duplicate though.

Comment: @Greg - As a "bonus Question" I can get away with it. As a fresh one, I don't stand a chance. I also thought of it while typing up this one.  Also - I'm researching iPhone development and I want to learn objective-c for that reason.

Comment: It sounds like you're really looking for this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/113547/iphone-development-on-windows

Comment: You are absolutely not going to build any iPhone apps on Windows if that's what all these silly threads are leading up to.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_Sharp_%28programming_language%29

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objective-C

Bonus:  Objective-C can be compiled by GCC, which can run on Windows.

Answer (score 6):

No.  Essentially: Objective C is from Apple and C# is from Microsoft.  That's a gross oversimplification, but it's close enough.

Comment: +1 for the courage to make a gross oversimplification that is, nevertheless as you say, close enough.

Comment: I actually am told by some friends that I am the 'master of simplification' lol. I just need to learn a new language, get a new computer and then voila, an iPhone app! It should take... um ... a few hours... lol

Comment: Thanks, GregS. I thought I was going to be eviscerated for that one.  Glad to see it was read in the hasty spirit it was intended.

Answer (score 1):

No. Objective-C was developed around the same time as C++ (late 1980s), and C# was developed much more recently (early 2000s).

Answer (score 1):

Objective C can be thought of as a thin layer on top of 'C'. It was designed in the early '80s and Steve Jobs used it for the NeXT development. Since OSX is built upon that foundation,  Mac / iPhone development use Objective C

Answer (score 1):

Essentially:

Objective-C is an object-oriented layer on top of C.  It's a combination of C and Smalltalk.

C# is a reworking of Java, which is a simplification of C++, which is a different object-oriented layer on top of C.

They're cousins -- both come from C originally -- but they went down different paths.

Comment: C# may have similarities to Java, but it is by no means a "reworking" of it.

Comment: Matt -- I look forward to your answer to this question, then.

Answer (score 0):

So, the difference between the two is clear.

Can you use Objective C on platform X?  Of course, it's in gcc, but the only current platform that has really good Objective C libraries is OS X, although there is GnuSTEP (which is not really mature).  So, it really depends on what you want to do with the language.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no. The two languages aren't the same. One very important difference to note is that Objective C uses a very [thin run-time system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runtime_system) to run iOS applications while C# targets [Common Language Runtime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Language_Runtime) (CLR) which is a full blown [virtual execution system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Execution_System) (VES).

Objective C likely to get overshadowed by swift language which is a new offering from Apple targeting iOS platform.