# iPhone SDK for windows. Which one?

Tags: iphone, windows

I am between those two SDKs for windows

http://www.dragonfiresdk.com/index.htm

http://www.airplaysdk.com/

Has anyone used them before? Which one to buy?

Comment: Purely speculation but that DragonFire looks like a waste of money... what's so difficult about setting up an OpenGL ES window on your PC and coding your game in C++? The only development you would need to do on a Mac / Objective-C is to generate a barebones app to initialize your game code, probably would take less than half an hour to get a C++/OpenGL ES app created in Windows to run on an iPhone.

Comment: I believe there's more discussion about this in the answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/113547/iphone-development-on-windows

Comment: Go buy a real mac.

Comment: Yes I think I'll buy one cause all the frameworks I've seen so far require XCODE to build iPhone apps...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After lots of searching and testing I think I'm going to buy a macmini and write my apps in Objective-C. Actually all the solutions out there need XCODE.
I've found though some good frameworks and SDKs for windows and for coding using your web design skills:

- [ELIPS STUDIO 3](http://developer.openplug.com/)
- [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/)
- [Appcelerator](http://www.appcelerator.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Unity?

Note that http://www.apple.com/macmini/ is less than Airplay Pro…