# Iphone C# development

Tags: c#, iphone

I wanted to use monotouch, but unfortunately I don't have $400 to spend.

So I found xmlvm http://www.xmlvm.org/ and I it seems It can crosscompile .net bytecode to objective c.

But, I'm not sure, are there any wrappers? What else would I need to start developing for the iphone using xmlvm??

Comment: Before looking into it further, I'd recommend reading this previous post on developing for the iPhone from a non-Apple platform.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/113547/iphone-development-on-windows

Comment: Nothing comes for free, especially on Apple/Mac/iPhone platform.

If you have a Mac, Objective C is still the cheapest way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [Unity 3D](http://unity3d.com/unity/), with [C# Scripts](http://unity3d.com/support/documentation/ScriptReference/index.Writing_Scripts_in_Csharp.html).

Comment: Unity is based on MonoTouch and you also need to purchase licenses.

Comment: I believe it is possible to create basic iPhone apps in C# with the free version, BUT you are correct that you do need to pay US$399 for the version that supports multitouch, accelleromoter, etc. http://unity3d.com/unity/licenses.html

Answer (score 2):

For the record: note that with the recent release of the iPhone OS version 4.0 SDK, Apple have outlawed using all forms of using cross-compiled languages on the iPhone OS family of devices.