# Best windows iphone app development alternative

Tags: iphone, windows

What do you think is the best way to develop iphone apps on windows? What are the pros / cons of your method, and why do you use it over other options? How complex is your method in relation to other options?

I am more interested in standalone and web apps but fell free to discuss gaming graphics.

Yes I know you need to build on a mac to be able to put it on the app store, so no "use a mac" answers please.

Comment: Perhaps just read these answers: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/113547/iphone-development-on-windows

Or these 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/377672/ipod-touch-iphone-development-on-windows

Comment: I was hoping that people who share their experiences about what worked for them. I did extensive reading about this issue on SO and the net before asking...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Running mac OS X in a VMware virtual machine did the job. Easy to do using instructions that can be found with a few quick google searches. This is against the OS X terms of service however...

Comment: End User License Agreement, not Terms of Service. There's also "Hackintosh", where you install it as the native OS.

Answer (score 4):

If you are creating web applications, then all you need is a text editor to create your web pages and an iPhone to test the results. If you want to create a standalone application, there is a project called [winChain](http://code.google.com/p/winchain/) that claims to be able to setup an iPhone development toolchain on Windows (DISCLAIMER: I have not ever tried using it, so for all I know, the executable could be a trojan horse). One other thing you might consider... you might want to consider [Android development](http://developer.android.com/) given that the [SDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/) supports development on Windows.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I would rather do android development too, right now I don't have a choice unfortunately.

Answer (score 4):

No ones mentioned phonegap? You can develop with 1 code base, and then compile to multiple platforms.

http://www.kintek.com.au/web-design-blog/developing-for-the-iphone-and-ipad-by-runing-os-x-10-6-snow-leopard-on-a-pc/

This is a post all about it and how to get t

Answer (score 2):

Try Airplay SDK (www.airplaysdk.com) Standard C++ to AppStore no mac required.

If it doesn't work you're holding it wrong ;)

Answer (score 2):

You should take a look at marmalade http://www.madewithmarmalade.com/ I learned about it from Thomas Henshell of Mirthwerx Games. You still need to join Apple's IOS Developer Program (which at the time of this writing is $99/year). Hope this helps. Supports development on many devices ala phonegap. Even Windows 8 mobile

Answer (score 1):

first of all specify your requirement

if you want to develop web application then it can be develop on windows but its not best way.

but if you want to develop iPhone Native App which uses COCOA Touch API then you will compulsorily go with Mac,no other alternatives for that.

you can develop web App as well as Native App using the COCOA Touch API on MAC.

if any other confusion then leave a comment...and if you satisfy with ans then mark it as correct by clicking check mark sign it will help other guys to refer.

enjoy...

Answer (score 1):

The best way is always use a real mac that loaded with the latest iOS SDK. If you only have a PC, you can rent a Mac remotely from [macincloud.com](http://www.macincloud.com). It allows you to access an actual Mac server using the windows Remote Desktop Connection (RDP) program. You pay a monthly fee of about $20-$30 and you can start practicing right away.

Answer (score 1):

- There actually is a great way to develop iPhone apps on the PC without having to jailbreak your iPhone. Rhomobile has created a hosted development tool called RhoHub that solves this problem and also also gives you some other valuable features like building apps online for all smartphones without having to install SDKs locally. Check it out for free at www.rhohub.com

Answer (score 0):

Look into Mono and MonoTouch for .Net developers. It is rapidly improving.  Good luck!

Comment: Is this some sort of sick joke?

Comment: I think that MonoTouch may be outlawed by the iPhone OS4 T&Cs.

Comment: You cant run monotouch on windows. Monotouch is for Mac OS X. It allows you to write C# code for interface builder - which requires OS X at this stage. Hardly windows development. http://monotouch.net/FAQ

Comment: Burger, that doesn't mean he shouldn't look into it.

Comment: @RedEye I never said he shouldn't.

Comment: My point was simply that there are options for .NET developers... whether you're developing in MAC OS X or windows environments. I just went out and got a mac for myself. And I run Windows 7 with VMWare, and bootcamp.