# iphone environment setup for windows

Tags: iphone, ios

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iPhone development on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/113547/iphone-development-on-windows)

I need to develop an iPhone application. I have Windows XP operating system. How can I configure iOS development environment in Windows XP?

Answer (score 5):

You can't. iPhone development requires XCode, which only runs on Mac OS X.

Answer (score 1):

On windows you could try to build native application using Web technologies, and software like http://appcelerator.com/ . You're using one of preferable web-languages (PHP, Ruby, etc.) and it will be converted to ObjectiveC.

Answer (score 0):

There is **no chance** to develop an iPhone application on the windows...

and also you can't do it on other than mac pc(you must have iMac,Mac mini,or Mac book)

you can install a Mac OS on general non mac pc.

but you can't install iPhone SDK successfully on that system...

So there is no chance to develop iPhone Application on the Windows as wel as non-Mac machine...strong text

Comment: Not completely true, people have got XCode working with the iPhone SDK on Hackintoshes, including applying the necessary keys for deployment onto hardware.  Personally given the not unreasonable cost of a Mac Mini (a secondhand one if necessary, just has to be intel) I wouldn't recommend it, but it is possible.

Comment: Hey Cruachan
from my observation that you have never done iPhone development.
then how can you justify that my answer is not completely true ?
don't justify any thing prior to do experiment on that thing...

Comment: there are enough examples which show that it is possible.

Comment: Of course I've done iPhone development, previously on a MacBook and currently on a new Mac Mini.  And there's a number of reports on both SO and the web of people running iPhone development environments on Hackintoshes, I strongly believe it's not optimal myself, but it has been done (unless people are posting lies for just to confuse others - yeah right ;-) )

Answer (score 0):

On Windows you can't do that. But you can maybe do it on your pc. You could try to install a Mac OS on your PC. For that consultate http://osx86.thefreesuite.com/ or http://www.hackint0sh.org/. However this is not rellay easy and you main have some disadvantages, like not fully working XCode and so on. Additionally its not very easy to install.

You could also search in the Internet for a Mac OS image which can be virtualized on PCs (e.g. by using VMWare).

Note: this is not fully legal as far as I know.