# Code::blocks and iPhone development

Tags: iphone, ide, multiplatform

Is it possible to use Code::Blocks to develop for iPhone? I mean if I may include the necessary frameworks, do remote debugging, etc. I never used Code::Blocks but it seems a good choice for multiplatform development. I saw that it easy to integrate gcc in the IDE on Windows(it also has a setup with mingw).

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that's possible.  Code::Blocks writes wxWidgets code, which, on OSX is built on top of Carbon, not Cocoa.  Even if it were Cocoa, it probably wouldn't be UIKit/CocoaTouch.

Even if they made a port that was written against UIKit, there might be an issue with the Terms of Service that says you can't use other frameworks.  You are supposed to write in Obj-C/C/C++ against UIKit directly.  They probably wouldn't have any idea, but who knows--seems like it's not worth it.

I am a former wx user and now iPhone developer.  ObjC/CocoaTouch/Interface Builder is much nicer and worth learning if you want to make iPhone apps.

If you want multi-platform development, I'd watch out, because Apple seems to be specifically targeting it in their terms of service.  For games, so far, it appears that Unity framework games are still being approved.

Comment: I use C++/OpenGL and there is no problem that Code::Blocks uses wxWidgets. My question is that if may I select target - Simulator/Device, SDK version, plist-file and things thare are in Xcode and aren't in Visual Studio for example.

Comment: Oh, I thought you were using it to generate wxWidget API code (to their components, not OpenGL).

Comment: @Felics - You'll need to integrate xcodebuild (the command-line Xcode tool for compiling your iPhone project) with Code::Blocks to get it to build your application.  However, this will only work on the Mac.  Anything else will require the suggestions here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/113547/iphone-development-on-windows

Comment: I have a Mac and I don't want to develop on Win for iPhone. I just want to be able to develop common code(render, AI, gameplay, etc.) and have same IDE/project on both platforms.