# How can i develop IPhone application on Windows just for testing?

Tags: iphone, windows-7

I want to get a feel of Iphone and develop applications like HelloWorld just for testing. I surfed google and some of them show a painful procedure of installing Snow Leopard on PC which i don't want to risk because if something goes wrong my all programs installed will be useless and that would waste another 1 week of mine. I do not want to sell my applications in App Store. Is there is any way to program for Iphone on Windows 7?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You will need to buy a mac afaik.

Comment: Doing a search for "iphone windows" I see at least nine variants of this question, including [iPhone development on Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/113547/iphone-development-on-windows).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of my friends is running Snow Leopard on `VirtualBox`(which is free) on Windows 7, everything seems OK to him. You can install either retail version of Snow Leopard or OSX86 version.

Some useful links:

http://zijric.com/2010/07/install-mac-os-x-snow-leopard-on-windows-using-virtualbox/

http://www.taranfx.com/install-snow-leopard-virtualbox

Answer (score 1):

There are some SDK like [Dragon Fire SDK](http://www.dragonfiresdk.com/index.htm) but these sdk use their own libraries. If you want to develop using the Cocoa Touch framework you must have a Mac.

Answer (score 1):

You can always try `VMWare` to see if that route works (haven't tried it myself).  They also have these additional efforts: http://www.osx86project.org/ and http://www.hackintosh.com/

Comment: +1 on the VMWare method. It's by far the most painless way to try out Xcode on a non-mac. Beware of possible EULA violations though -- previously you weren't allowed to do this, although techincally possible...