# Can we compile objective c on windows?

Tags: objective-c, windows

Can we compile objective c on windows platform?

Comment: If someone has answered your question, you should mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: You might want to add more context to the question (although it's been fairly well answered below :-) I.e. why do you want to do this?

Comment: @Derek, probably avoid having to buy a Mac to write iPhone apps.

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPhone development on Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/113547/iphone-development-on-windows)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Quick answer: no, not to any useful degree.

Long answer: Objective-C is just a standard language, and GCC compiles it just fine.  But when most people talk about Objective-C, they are including Apple's (formerly NEXTstep) libraries, as the bare language isn't too useful without them.  There are projects around to let you use these libraries on non-Mac systems, for example [GNUstep](http://www.gnustep.org/), but from my experience they are immature and more trouble than they are worth.  I haven't looked recently, but I wouldn't spend too much effort trying to get it to work.

Comment: And that's a much better answer than I could have given you through googling. If you're stuck on the GCC bit and still want to do so, check http://www.roseindia.net/iphone/objectivec/compiling-objective-c.shtml

Comment: GCC/Mingw indeed has an objective-C compiler, but I fear it will be missing a lot of Apple specific functionality on the runtime side, because... well.. that functionality is Mac specific :)

Answer (score 2):

If your framework needs are basic, you can try cocotron, but I understand it is not yet "there" in many areas. http://www.cocotron.org/