# How new of a Mac do I need for iPhone / iPad dev?

Tags: development-environment, iphone

So apparently if I want to try my hand at iPhone/iPad dev I need a [mac computer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/113547/iphone-development-on-windows).

But I'm cheap, and don't think dropping $1000 on an MacBook just to *try* iPhone development. SO I'm fishing through Craigslist and eBay and pawn shops looking for second-hand-ers, all the while wondering, how old is *too old* for iPhone dev?

In particular, I've been offered an old Mac Mini from 2005 at no cost, and am wondering if this will do the job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, to develop for the latest iOS, you will need to have the latest version of Mac OS X, and you will also need to be running on an Intel platform. So unless the Mac Mini is running Snow Leopard and has an Intel chip, it won't do the trick. That said, there are some alternatives such as buying a [refurbished Mac](http://store.apple.com/us/browse/home/specialdeals/mac?afid=p219|GOUS&cid=OAS-US-KWG-CPUDiscount/Refurb-US) or you could try your hand at [Android development](http://developer.android.com/) instead of iPhone development.

Answer (score 2):

1. VMWare workstation: $189
2. OSX Snow Leopard Retail: $30
3. Depriving Apple of money for overpriced, underpowered PCs: Priceless.

Answer (score 0):

As long as it has an intel CPU and you should be fine.