# Can I successfully do iPhone/iPad website development/testing on Windows?

Tags: iphone, ipad, html, css, mobile-safari

Can I successfully do iPhone/iPad **web development (not native apps)** on Windows, and without having an iPhone/iPad device?

I.e. work like PSD-to-iPhone-optimized XHTML/CSS layout.

I’m interested to learn about and make iPhone/iPad optimized websites. Any tips? How different will it be from desktop? What’s different other than the smaller screen?

Comment: *Sooooo* many duplicates: [iPhone development on Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/113547/iphone-development-on-windows), along with most everything in its Linked list.

Comment: gnovice, +1.  I think this should be closed.

Comment: @gnovice -my question is related to "Web Development" not about iphone/ipad native apps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From experience I will say the only true way to test for the iPad is to test on an iPad.  I have been developing a site in html5 specifically for an iPad and we initially used the iPhone to test.  The drag function we had implemented with jQuery had worked almost perfectly on the iPhone but after the client had tested on the iPad they came back to us and said the function did not work period and they were correct.

I guess this could change depending on what type of development you are doing.  From experience I would say either A. Make some trips to the apple store B. Make friends with iPad owner C. Buy and iPad

Answer (score 2):

yes for an ipohne emulator... try MobiOne.
It's a good application to test the pages in iphone like environment.

http://www.genuitec.com/mobile/

Answer (score 1):

I don’t think you can really do iPhone/iPad development successfully without an iPhone/iPad at all, whether on Windows, Mac or Commodore 64.

If you’re serious about iPhone/iPad development, how could you not try your software out yourself on the devices it’s going to run on? Your clients are going to want code that works on the iPhone/iPad. You need an iPhone/iPad to check that it works.

Answer (score 0):

if your developing a web app then i think you can use this: http://ipadpeek.com/

Comment: my experience is that it delivers inaccurate results!

Answer (score -1):

The answer is: Yes you can absolutely do iPhone and iPad website development on a Windows PC.

However, you really should/must **test** the result on an actual iPhone/iPod Touch/iPad. Especially if you are integrating in any way with special device features like the dialing feature of the phone. (Yes you can have phone numbers in a webpage trigger dialing when you tap on them.)

However, you can do the bulk of the development on Windows, testing the WebApp in Safari or Chrome, which are the most fully compliant HTML5 WebKit based browsers out there.
Also highly recommend using an HTML5 touch framework like jQuery Mobile or Sencha Touch. This will go a long way to ensuring that your WebApp is optimized for the screen size and touch gestures of the mobile devices.

Remember that you can't deploy a pure WebApp to the app store, only download it from a website. You'll need a native wrapper like PhoneGap for that. And to compile a PhoneGap wrapped WebApp you'll need XCode on a Mac.

But there's a lot of power in adding your WebApp to the home screen on iOS. No native code involved and you get a full screen webapp with a home screen icon, loading image and no browser toolbars. Highly recommended.