# How would you build iPhone apps without the use of the iPhone SDK?

Tags: iphone

If you wanted to avoid the agreement to use the iPhone SDK, you'd have to not use it.

Comment: Several of the answers on the question [iPhone development on Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/113547/iphone-development-on-windows) present potential technical solutions for working around using Xcode and the iPhone SDK, but Toastor is right in that these do not circumvent legal issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to jailbreak, you have one option:

- Web app

I'm not sure what the toolchain is on the jailbreak side, but I suspect you may be able to avoid the official SDK that way, but, obviously, you've cut your potential market by at least 90%.

Answer (score 1):

Even if you would successfully avoid the SDK and the agreements that come along with it, you'd have to agree to the app store terms of use once you'd like to submit something. Same goes for development certificates, mobile provision profiles,...

So, the best answer to your question propably would be: I wouldn't, and you shouldn't.