# Do I have any hope of messing around with creating an app for my new iPod touch without buying a Mac?

Tags: ipod-touch, ipod

I'd really rather not buy a Mac just to do this.  I know there have been efforts to make it possible, but it's hard to tell which, if any, are worth my time.

Thanks!

Comment: Duplicated *sooooo* many times: [iPhone development on Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/113547/iphone-development-on-windows)

Answer (score 1):

I've wondered about this sort of thing before... I found this thread about the same topic from another forum: http://ask.metafilter.com/110466/Anyway-to-develop-iPhoneiTouch-apps-without-investing-in-a-Mac

Basically, there are ways of dubious legality to run OSX without having a Mac so this would be a possiblity for a testing environment if you want to go through the trouble, I have heard of the VMware OSX images before and this may be easiest way to do it, haven't tried it myself though

Answer (score 1):

There is a project call [xmlvm](http://www.xmlvm.org/) that supposedly supports crosscompiling Java code to [iPhone/Objective-C](http://www.xmlvm.org/iphone/), I suppose it would also work on an IPod Touch (though I'm not sure, I think that since the code won't be properly signed the device will need to be jailbroken, can you do that on an Ipod Touch?). The links seems to be down (for me) at the moment though, but the google cache of the pages gives some details.

Answer (score 0):

### Not as far as I know

They all require the iPhone SDK which is only available with XCode (which is Apple software).

Comment: @Gabriel: Why don't you explain?

Comment: he probably means something like this: http://www.osnews.com/story/21564/Building_a_Hackintosh_Apple_Can_t_Sue_You_For

Comment: @ergo: Ah, so let's cobble together a computer to develop on. That is anexcellent idea.