# Objective C on Windows system

Tags: iphone

Can you tell me what software I must used to develop for iPhone on Windows Operating System?

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPhone development on Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/113547/iphone-development-on-windows)

Answer (score 3):

You cannot develop for the iPhone on Windows. You need MacOS to run the SDK, and MacOS generally runs only on Apple computers - unless you want to run it inside VMWare or VirtualBox (hardware virtualization must be supported by your CPU). But you still need MacOS for this.

Answer (score 0):

It's against Terms of Service to run OSX on a non Apple computer, but look up `hackintosh` in google for more information on it.  As for someone else recommending a Mac Mini, I would personally save up and get an iMac or MacBook Pro over that, there's just so much more you get for not much more.

Comment: The question was about developing on Windows (which the linked duplicate already addresses anyway).

Comment: technically you cannot write an app on Windows, I was giving information on how to do it on a PC.