# How do I test responsive design font without actually having iphone

Tags: iphone, css, html, responsive-design

I implemented concept of responsive design but now we face a issue. The content seems to be fit in nicely inside the frame. I've used `max-device-width` and so on. My font-sizes all use a fix sized pixels that is 12px and so on. Now when I gave it to my client he complains it looks super tiny on iPhone. I don't actually have an iPhone to test the designs.

Is there anyway to test it without using the actual device? a simulator or something? I tested it on Chrome by resizing the browser window but on actual device it looks super tiny and very difficult to read. Attached is one screenshot:

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure if this will solve your problem, but I use this: [http://www.responsinator.com](http://www.responsinator.com)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3882233/iphone-browser-simulator-for-windows

Comment: If you have a Mac, you can test the site in the iOS Simulator that comes with Xcode.

Comment: @all: Well responsinator shows correct layout but the client complains he sees tiny. On responsinator I correcly see only 5 songs but on real iPhone I see 15 :(

Answer (score 5):

If you have Chrome browser than you should try to change the [user agent](http://googlesystem.blogspot.ro/2011/12/changing-user-agent-new-google-chrome.html).

**Step 1:** Open Chrome => go to the desired website => press <kbd>F12</kbd> => the Elements Panel should appear.

**Step 2:** Click on the `Settings` icon. It should be in the lower right corner (if the design hasn't changed):

[image]

**Step 3:** Click on the `Overrides` tab:

[image]

**Step 4:** Check the `User Agent` and select a device from the drop-down list. Don't forget to check the `Device metrics`, where you can add custom values too:

[image]

More information at the [Chrome Developer Tools](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/mobile-emulation?hl=en).

---

#### *UPDATE:*

For Chrome version 32+ see [this link](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/mobile-emulation) for chrome Developer Tools.

Comment: Correct. I now see 15 songs. ios 4 resolution is 960×640 and I see 15 songs in that. Now how do I solve that? If make bigger font size, the songs look super big while on desktop. Any ideas?

Comment: You should try [media queries](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/). But I don't understand clearly your problem.

Comment: If it's "Correct" than you could select it as accepted answer. Thnx!

Answer (score 1):

You could try : [responsive.is](http://responsive.is)
The site has different orientations and devices on which you can see how the site may render.

Answer (score 1):

Screenfly by quirktools is what I use. Works like a charm for me!

http://quirktools.com/screenfly/

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use http://www.isresponsive.com enable you to test responsive design on different devises.