# How to debug website which only chrashs on iphone/ipad under windows

Tags: javascript, iphone, windows, debugging, safari

after some time googel'ing I decided to ask for help on SO.

Is there a possibilty to debug iphone/ipad mobile safari browser on windows?

I read the tip in [iPhone Browser simulator for Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3882233/iphone-browser-simulator-for-windows) to set the user agent of safari to the one of iphone/ipad but it didn't help.

My problem is the following:
I have a page what uses JavaScript and the page works fine in:

desktop firefox + waterbox, IE, Opera, Chrome, Safari (Safari user agent), Safari (iphone/ipdad user agent)

But it the JS doesn't work when I use the page with my fully updated iphone / ipad with its up-to-date mobile safari.

I know desktop safari is only version 5 with unknown if safari 6 will ever come - so I think that the user agents of this safari version are possibly "outdated".

Any suggestions how I can debug my page under iphone/ipad circumstances to find my mistake?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Ok i don't know how to debug iphone/ipad on windows, but my problem was that up-to-date safari on ipad/iphone (and chrome on mac, [but not on linux/windows]) hat problems with the JS-"OnClick"-Event. Had to change it to "OnChange"