# Is it possible create a iphone application by using java and LWUIT framework?

Tags: java, iphone, lwuit

Is it possible create a IPhone application by using java and LWUIT framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There appears to be a [rudimentary LWUIT Microemulator](http://markus.heberling.net/lang/en/2008/11/24/microemulator-on-iphone/) in development, but the author states that this requires jailbroken iPhones.  I would not rely on this for anything serious, because I doubt something based on this will ever appear on the App Store.

A better bet would be to learn Objective-C and the native APIs, or use an alternative platform like MonoTouch.

Comment: Is it possible to develop a iphone application on windows os?

Comment: @bhakki - See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/113547/iphone-development-on-windows .  In short, not really.  You're far better off getting a Mac and learning the native development environment.

Answer (score 1):

yes it is possible, take a look at codenameone.com project, it's a cross platform mobile framework where the ui part is a fork of LWUIT

Comment: @ Chen, I already developed lot of applications. Currently also I have working with codename one. Anyway nice answer and its helps for future developers. :)

Comment: Thanks, hoping other developers will pick this up too ;)

Answer (score 0):

It is currently not possible using any language other than objective-c.

Comment: Ok. but I heard LWUIT supports in IPhone. Is it true?

Comment: Not true, you can use C++, C and you are allowed to use third party frameworks to compile your apps (Flash, unity and more). Don't know about LWUIT

Comment: The above comment isn't factually true. Sander is correct but somewhat outdated. Latest Apple guidelines permit everything including interpreted VM's (not JIT's) which is what Adobe is using in its action script compiler. LWUIT actually runs rather well on the iPhone but unfortunately we can't publish the VM mostly because of the complexity of licenses involved (you will need to package the VM with your application). I hope to have some news on this matter before 2012.