# Is it possible to write and test an iPhone application via VS2010?

Tags: iphone, visual-studio-2010, windows-7, ipod-touch

| Windows 7 Ultimate | Visual Studio 2010 Professional | - Is it possible to write and test an iPhone/iPod touch application through Visual Studio 2010? If so, is there a template to do so? Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPhone development on Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/113547/iphone-development-on-windows)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look into "MonoTouch".

But generally, if you know objective-C you're better off NOT using a round-about way of developing an iPhone app like this.

Comment: Right on Monotouches main page, it says: "Please note that MonoTouch requires a Mac, Apple's iPhone SDK and you must be part of Apple's iPhone Developer Program to test and deploy your software on a device and to redistribute your code."

Comment: This is true, but the actual development and testing can be done with a windows OS. Testing on a device and submitting to Apple will require the Apple hardware/software however. The only reason why i know this is because I saw a friend use MonoTouch extensively.

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely, Positively, Unequivocally, "no".

Xcode only, Under Mac OS

Comment: See above comment under "MonoTouch".