# How do I start developing iPhone apps? and can it be done on Windows?

Tags: iphone

Hey everyone,
I want to learn how to develop iPhone apps, I heard that I need to get a mac in order to do so,
So I'm here to ask if its possible to develop apps in windows, and if its possible, where do I start?
P.S: Some guy told me that I need some sort of a certificate in order to develop apps,
well is it true? and if it is true, how do i get it?,
And will I need to "jailbreak" or something like that in order to install my app on iphones if i dont have the certificate?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/113547/iphone-development-on-windows

Comment: You pretty much need a MAC.  Unfortunate, but true.

Comment: This question gets asked about once a week, and nothing has changed. Do a search; you'll find more information than you ever wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- The supported way to develop is via XCode on a machine running OS X.
- You need a certificate to upload an application to a device.
- You can develop and test on the simulator without a certificate.

Answer (score 1):

Only way without buying Mac hardware is to use a virtual machine with OSX installed. It is not great but doable.

Some month back I wrote a bit about this subject [here](http://www.greck.eu/blog/2010/06/06/iphone-programming-do-i-need-a-mac/).

Using OSX in a virtual machine is not something I would recommend to do permanently. It is more like doing it for a while to understand if programming for iPhone is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can find all the right information over here: http://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/index.action

I thought you do need a mac and you do need a kind of certificate, I am not sure about the jailbreak part.. but i don;t think that is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think its possible.
http://forums.macrumors.com/archive/index.php/t-560048.html

But I might be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

At first, programming AppStore Compatible applications is only possible on Mac OS X.

You need a certificat if you wan't to test your application on your iPhone and publish it. With out the certificat you can still use the iPhone emulator, which is included into the iPhone SDK.

Answer (score 0):

See the linked previously asked StackOverflow question for the details, but you do need a Mac. Really. Buy a cheap Mac Mini on eBay if you're short on money. And then buy a book on iPhone development that has good ratings on Amazon :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it in Windows, you have to run Mac OSX somewhere. You could Hackintosh your windows box but as you are complete newbie to Mac OSX, it's very tricky. Buy a second hand Intel Core Duo Mac Mini from Ebay if you haven't got much cash and make sure it has Snow Leopard installed or install it from cd yourself.