# ios sdk for windows xp

Tags: ios

Can any one provide details of "ios sdk for windows xp" so that  we can develop Ipad application in Windows environment.

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPhone development on Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/113547/iphone-development-on-windows)

Comment: Please search for existing questions/answers before you post a new question - this topic has already been covered in some detail.

Comment: http://monotouch.net/ should be of specific interest.

Answer (score 1):

There is no iOS SDK for Windows.

Answer (score 1):

YES it is possible! You can develop for iOS on a PC. Almost all versions of windows are supported, including Windows XP. You can build iPad and iPhone apps using the SDK. It is called **Dragon Fire SDK** and it allows you to create iOS apps using Visual Studio C++. Dragon Fire SDK is very limited in it's features, but the company is constantly updating the SDK. Dragon Fire SDK is really aimed at creating games (Open GL ES), although they recently announced a possibility of an Enterprise version of the SDK which would allow you to create lifestyle, productivity, utility, and other types of apps. I used it for almost a year before switching to a Macintosh Computer and getting Xcode, and I was very pleased with everything. The company was devoted to helping you create your dream app, and they had lots of resources, help forums, and communities to answer your questions about app building with the PC. The SDK allows you to develop your app in C or C++ and then test it using a real iPhone or iPad simulator. Dragon Fire SDK ranges from the basic starter kit, $50, to the ultimate version which allows for iPhone and iPad Dev, priced at $150. Dragon Fire SDK is created by Zumisoft. As far as distributing your app, Zumisoft will distribute it for you, but the downfall of that is that your app must be a FREE app and updates cost $10 each. The other way is to distribute it through the App Store for $99 and do all the cool fancy stuff you want.

LINKS:

[Dragon Fire SDK Home](http://www.dragonfiresdk.com/)

[Dragon Fire SDK Products](http://www.dragonfiresdk.com/products.htm)

[Apple iOS Developer Center](http://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/)

Best of Luck!

Happy App Building!

Comment: @Anjana please view this post, it may help you

Answer (score 1):

If you are really serious about the iPad app, buy a Mac ;)