# compiling and signing xcode project on Windows

Tags: iphone, ios, windows, xcode

I am using an application that produce me the xcode project  that I have implemented on windows. So in order to test it on iphone i have to use a mac. I am wondering is there any way to compile and sign the xcode project so I can get *.ipa or *.app.
Thanks.

Comment: I'm almost sure you can't do it natively. You must either have a Mac OS vm with XCode or a Hackintosh installation.

Comment: I know Adobe-flex have accomplished it in some way.

Comment: Possible a duplicate of [Develop iPhone applications on Windows (with Virtualbox etc)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5635915/develop-iphone-applications-on-windows-with-virtualbox-etc)

Comment: Adobe have a compiler for their ActionScript to ipa. I thought you were asking about generic obj-c code.

Comment: I believe Adobe also use generic obj-c as well since I have read on their website that they create native obj-c code.

Comment: I'm not sure where you have read that, all I can come up with is [this](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/logged_in/abansod_iphone.html), and it has no mention of conversion to objective-c.

Comment: No I want to implement on windows. (console or obj-c code)

Comment: You will still be using your PC with Windows, but you will be running Xcode inside its own window. You will also be able to read your windows file from within your virtual environment. Your goal will be achieved with *.ipa or *.app files. So no need for any Mac hardware.

Comment: All you need to do is to learn some of the basics about Xcode. It is rather trivial to build, run & sign code. Maybe it is worth it, considering that the alternative is to buy a Mac.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I develop for iPhone using a Windows development machine?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22358/how-can-i-develop-for-iphone-using-a-windows-development-machine)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you install [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) which enables you to run Mac OS X. Buying a Mac OS X license is rather cheap and VirtualBox is free. If you register at Apple Developer you could download Xcode for free. I have successfully used VirtualBox to setup similar environments, where I used Ubuntu as the host operating system.

The following might be of interest: [Develop iPhone applications on Windows (with Virtualbox etc)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5635915/develop-iphone-applications-on-windows-with-virtualbox-etc).

Comment: Last time I tried to use Virtual Box to run OS X on non-Apple hardware, it failed pretty badly. Has it improved? Have you gotten Virtual Box to run OS X on non-Apple hardware?

Comment: Heh, the first one involves torrenting a complete OS X hackintosh distribution and the second one assumes you've done so -- with the vague mention that probably the real disc would work too. If you'll run a torrent-acquired hacked-up OS X installation you've got more faith in humanity than I do. :)

Comment: If you're running VirtualBox on Apple hardware it will run OS X, even when the host OS is Windows. You only need a hacked OS X image if you're not running on Apple hardware.

Answer (score -2):

No, it is illegal and is only allowed on licensed Mac OS X software.