# can I virtualize my Mac OS system?

Tags: xcode, macos, virtualization, virtualbox

**Note: I understand this is not strictly about "development", but in the earlier threads I link to below the community decided that questions on how to develop for iOS on non-Apple platforms were admissible.**

I have a 2009 (Intel) Apple MacBook that I no longer use regularly. However, I would like to continue dabbling in iOS development using Xcode. Is it possible for me to move the entire system into a VirtualBox/VMWare image and run it under Linux inside VirtualBox/VMWare?

I have checked [earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5635915/develop-iphone-applications-on-windows-with-virtualbox-etc) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2795768/developing-for-mac-without-a-mac) but I no longer have the installation media that came with the MacBook, on which those earlier answers rely. I am specifically interested in knowing if by shifting the entire system into a virtual disk image it will continue to work.

To clarify, I understand this might be in violation of the EULA. I paid for this computer and OS and am comfortable using the OS on a different machine while letting this particular laptop gather dust in a closet.

Thanks!
~l

Comment: goto http://www.hackintosh.com/ and/or http://apple.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it works. Mac OS still needs a ROM to boot. But you can patch VMware and you can download many MacOS VMware images. But sadly it didn't work for me on Linux.