# How can we build IPAD app

Tags: iphone, ipad

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iPhone development on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/113547/iphone-development-on-windows)

How can we build IPAD appon windows platform.

Comment: The iPad is not an acronym.

Answer (score 2):

You can't. Simple as that. You'll need xcode, or you use some kind of non-native platform to develop web-like applications, but still those most of the time need OSX. Not all though.

Answer (score 1):

If you're referring to a native iPad app, you can't on the windows platform at this stage (and it will be very unlikely it will ever be possible in the foreseeable future). However, if it's a web based iPad app it's possible.

Have a look [here](http://sixrevisions.com/web-applications/designing-web-apps-for-the-ipad/) as a starting point for seeing how web apps are possible on the iPad.

Answer (score 0):

There are [guides on the internet](http://www.hackintosh.com/) on how to run Mac OS X on 'normal' PCs, though it's not legal (the Mac OS X license allows Mac OS X only to run on Apple computers) and not supported either. Mac OS X is required to run [Xcode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xcode), the software used to create iPhone & iPad apps.

Answer (score 0):

You need a Mac OS. Buy new or used Mac or make a hackintosh. Then go to Apple Developer http://developer.apple.com/ for tools and samples.