# May I do development of iPhone using VMWare on XP?

Tags: iphone, macos, vmware, intel

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [iPhone development on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/113547/iphone-development-on-windows)

I am looking for some environment where I can develop an iPhone application. But my budget does not allow me to invest on mac machine. So can I do it on my Intel system using VMWare?

Comment: Quite simply, no. It violates the license agreement for Mac OS X. You are *only* allowed to run it on Apple hardware. The technical issues of how to make it work are off-topic here. Try [Super User](http://www.superuser.com/).

Comment: Not legally. Apple's licence does not allow OS X to be run on non-Apple branded hardware.

Comment: You can buy Mac mini (this is lesser in price).

Comment: A mac mini with Snow Leopard on it is cheaper than a Microsoft Windows Small Business Server license, and about 3 times the price of a regular Windows 7 Professional license.

Comment: @rdineiu Humm this is right but in comparison to buy a desktop of apple it is cheaper.

Comment: @Ishu, indeed, but if you have a Windows XP machine, then you most likely already have a keyboard, mouse and monitor.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5665682/iphone-dev-on-windows-using-vmware

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Follow the steps to install OS X in VMWare:

1. Download VMWare [here](http://downloads.vmware.com/d/details/wkst_713_win/ZGolYnRld3RiZGplaA).
2. [Purchase](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B001AMHWP8) a fully-licensed copy of Mac OS X Snow Leopard.
3. Extract the zip  file (you will have a folder).
4. Install VMWare and locate .vmx file(in above extracted folder) when you go to open option in VMWare.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

If you run into trouble with VMWare, another common alternative people will do is to buy used Mac hardware to develop on. You can get a four year old Mac/Macbook and throw some more ram into it and get a few more years out of it.

There is no real need to buy brand new hardware just to develop for iOS on. If you are just running XCode, an older machine will do just fine. It  won't be a speed queen for compiling, but it will get you what you need.

Check Craigslist/eBay for some used Mac's and save yourself a ton of cash (You may even have some friends that have upgraded to newer Macs and have their old laptops laying around).

It is also a great way to get iOS devices to do testing on.