# SDK for iphone app development in windows

Tags: iphone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iPhone development on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/113547/iphone-development-on-windows)

I am a beginner in iPhone application development.Is there any way to develop iPhone applications on Windows..please tell about free SDK kit which is compatible in windows

Can i use visual studio to develop iPhone applications in windows..? Is there any added patch which will make it work.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/113547/iphone-development-on-windows

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can also try PhoneGap or Titanium appcelerator for developing iPhone application and also both these technologies are not based in objective C. Maybe you can just have a look.

[Titanium Appcelerator](http://www.appcelerator.com/)

[PhoneGap](http://www.phonegap.com/)

Comment: Is it possible to use Titanium Accelerator to develop iPhone application in windows...does i need to install anything else

Answer (score 0):

For developing apps for iOS, you NEED to have a machine running on Mac OS.

Answer (score 0):

Xcode must be used to develop for the iOS (iPod touch, iPads and iPhones). XCode is the only platform for which the iPhone SDK is available, and Mac OS X is the only platform that allows XCode.

if you are planning on making say a game, you can use a multi-client engine like Unity3d or something similar, develop your app on windows, and test it live inside the engine. Although, you will still need a mac the day you wish to publish for the AppStore.

Answer (score 0):

To develop an iPhone/iPad application you need to have just two thing.

1. Mac OS on your PC.
2. XCode (3.0,4.0) as IDC with latest iOS SDK.

Answer (score 0):

You can purchase VMWare and get a Mac disk image for it which will run like a regular VM under Windows. However, as you can imagine, emulators like this run excruciatingly slowly and I honestly wouldn't recommend it.

You can get a second-hand Mac Mini for a couple of hundred pounds on eBay or brand new from Apple for the £600 mark. (again, less on other auction sites or classified ad sites)

Hope this helps.