# Is there any way to write iOS code in windows?

Tags: objective-c, ios

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I develop for iPhone using a Windows development machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22358/how-can-i-develop-for-iphone-using-a-windows-development-machine)

I am using windows 7. Now, I have started to write code of iOS. Is it possible to do it without buying an mac machine? Is there any tool to do that?

Comment: and many other http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11361269/develop-iphone-application-in-windows http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9595507/ios-development-on-windows  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/928656/iphone-sdk-on-windows-alternative-solutions  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6200733/sdk-for-iphone-app-development-in-windows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install Mac OS X on Virtual Machine. 
Even if you buy a copy of Mac OS X it is debatable if it is legal.

Also there could be problems submitting app as Application Loader may fail on virtual machine.

Another option is to use cross platform frameworks for development. In some cases you need mac only for final compilation and upload.

Here are some of such frameworks

- Adobe Air
- PhoneGap
- Marmalade SDK
- Unity
- Titanium

Answer (score 0):

Answering your question directly: yes, you can write iOS code in Windows. You can use a simple notepad or Notepad++ or any other text editor.

If you also want to compile your code the answer will be NO. You can not do it.

If you don't want to buy a Mac there are a few ways(please don't forget that they are illegal):

- Install Mac OS X on a virtual machine
- Install hackintosh

But you may spend more time configuring your hackintosh than actually doing some programming.

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can do iOS programming on windows 7. Please install vmware or virtualbox. And then install mac os on it. through xcode you can code for iPhone on that.