# Can I create and test iphone applications on windows? is there any simulator?

Tags: iphone

I am going to start building iphone applications , but i don't have Mac, can i do that on windows? can I use the virtual machine?

Comment: how u install mac os on window system?

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPhone development on Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/113547/iphone-development-on-windows)

Answer (score 0):

not that i'm aware of though there is MonoTouch but again i think that runs on a mac.

you can create a Mac virtual pc using vmware and the steps are online if you google mac vm i think.

google "mac vm on windows"

at least then you won't need to buy a mac

Comment: But still you cannot test the application in device.

Answer (score 0):

Buy a second-hand Mac Mini or similar from a reputable online auction site and you're there.

All you need then is Xcode which you can get from the Mac App Store (MacOSX 10.7+ for Xcode 4.1 or assuming you've subscribed to an Apple Developer program you can find older versions for older Macs)