# Starting development on ios platform with windows 7

Tags: iphone, ios

New to ios development, looking for some guides, Can I develop ios application on windows 7 having mac os as virtual machine, and if yes then what are the things that i need to install first to get started.

Comment: Do yourself a favor and get a Mac.

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPhone development on Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/113547/iphone-development-on-windows)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no legal way to develop iOS applications on Windows at the moment. Running Mac OS X in a VM on non-Apple hardware is a violation of Mac OS X EULA. If you hadn't mentioned a VM I would have voted to close this question as duplicate, as *Can I develop iOS apps on Windows?* is a very frequently question. The canonical answer is: *No, buy a cheap used Mac Mini.*

Comment: so i need mac mini having mac os x, is there some sort of ide in mac like visual studio

Comment: anything that is needed to be installed along with xcode, does it requires a framework or something

Comment: When you download and install Xcode you will get the latest Mac OS X and iOS SDKs.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can.  It's called hackintosh.  I purchased a $30 CD from an apple store and followed directions found on many sites, check youtube.  Yes, it violates the MAC OS X EULA.  I would say no less than 5% of iphone apps are developed this way, especially those developed in India (4 of 5 developers i've spoke with write code this way).

Should you purchase a Mac Mini and do it "right".  That's up to you.  The time i spent getting hackintosh up and running, I could have billed out enough hours to have purchased 5 mac mini's.

Answer (score 0):

You can do ***Virtual Machine*** on Windows for Mac but this will cause lots of a problem and its not worth the hassle.

You can leave out all the hackintosh stuff and try to do yourself in mac-mini

but if you are still insistent on using windows machine and comfortable with ***C#***
 then you can give a try on ***Xamarin.iOS***.

Microsoft has introduced ***[Xamarin Live Player](https://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2017/05/xamarin-live-player-almost-takes-the-mac-out-of-ios-development/)*** using which you can ***debug,develop and deploy*** the app completely in windows without the help of any Apple system but to sign and release the app to appstore you will need Apple System though