# Is it possible to develop (not distribute) iPhone applications on Windows using C/C++?

Tags: iphone, c++, windows

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iPhone development on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/113547/iphone-development-on-windows)

I am very used to coding in C/C++ on Microsoft Visual Studio. However, I'm very interested in learning how to write iPhone apps. I do not have a Mac (other than my iPhone). Is there a legal way to develop on Windows and then when it comes time to test on the real device or distribute the app commercially, that I pay for the Apple iPhone developer fee ($99/yr) and compile/ship the code on an actual Mac?

I just want to know if I can continue to work the technologies I already know in order to make iPhone apps? I came across a framework called Dragonfire SDK which looks exactly like what I'm looking for. However, I'm questioning the legality of all of this and what it will really take to get the code onto a real iPhone/app store. For now though, I mainly just want to be able to work with C/C++ and then test using an iPhone simulator of some sort. Is it possible to do this part on a PC?

Again, I'm willing to pay whatever development fees are required to distribute the app and when the time comes I'll find a real Mac to test/distribute on. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DragonFire SDK should work because it gets around the requirement for using a Mac by compiling your code on a Mac server. I don't use it; I program in Objective-C. There aren't really any largely negative reviews I could find online, but be careful because *it looks like they are going to charge you a lot to use it.*