# Developing for iOS under Windows

Tags: ios, windows, visual-c++

Some days ago I found a great project: vs-android.
It allows you to build Android projects from Visual Studio, and run them in emulator.
This is very cool, because of I like to develop in vs.

So I started to find something like vs-ios =)))

I found some toolchains that allow you compile ios app, under windows, but you can't run them in emulator or on a real device.
Or these toolchains are very old.
And the other problem is that there is no ios emulator for windows.

I found that there is a DragonFire SDK which allow you to develop, compile and run your ios apps under windows.
So, It means it is possible!

1. I have own crossplatform game engine written in C++. And I want to try everything to develop under windows in vs =)
   If there is a solution to do it, please help, even if this solution is VERY HARD to implementation.
2. Please, don't post unusefull links. I am really read a lot.
   Tell about your experience, not about what you heard from others =)))

P. S. I want to develop only in C++. Other variants is not a solution.

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicated - [iPhone development on Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/q/113547/194544)

Comment: I don't believe this question should've been closed as not constructive. English seems to be a second language, but apart from that its a legit question. . Plenty of games studios are developing mobile apps in Pure C++ - anything not leveraging UIKit and Cocoa could be a candidate for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot comment on the C++ side of things, but I can explain a method that work with a valid IPA.

Once you develop an IPA file, you can upload it to iTunes, if it is set up correctly.  No matter how it is created, though, to upload an app to iTunes, you need a Mac.  However, you don't have to buy one . . . just use the virtual Macs hosted by http://www.macincloud.com.  It is cheap and works on a PC.

You will have to use the Mac's keychain to create your certificates, but once you have the certs, you can develop the IPA file in Windows using your methods (probably) or Adobe Air (definitely). You then upload to the virtual Mac using DropBox (or other method).  From there, you will have to understand the Mac iTunes uploading process, which you can find in the Apple docs.