# How to create the Iphone application without MAC OS

Tags: iphone, ios, ios-simulator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iPhone development on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/113547/iphone-development-on-windows)

I am android developer. Now In our Company their is one new requirement for Iphone. I have  Downloaded all the Xcode and SDK that require for the development but we don't have mac m/c.

**without mac machine can we develop the application??**

**We got the below [link](http://www.genuitec.com/mobile/index.html) can we build our application with such 3rd party tool.** What they saying give code to them they will run and give ios application.

Is their any third party tool by using that we can develop our application for Iphone.

Means we will write the and give It to them they will compile our code and give the app file which then we will put Inside the Mobile and Test.

Please help If any one having the Idea!! Thanks In advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/113547/iphone-development-on-windows

Comment: Buy a refurbished "Mac mini".  http://www.apple.com/shop/browse/home/specialdeals/mac/mac_mini  or google "buy refurbished mac mini".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no Tool or Development environment available to develop iOS and Mac Application.

You must have **Mac OS and Mac machine** to develop them. You will need XCode installed on Mac OSX to code, run and test your application.

If you do not want to buy Mac you can install Mac OSX on PC referring this link thats called **Hackintosh**. This works fine on PC if you follow steps properly:

http://tonymacx86.blogspot.in/2011/07/xmove-multibeast-install-os-x-107-lion.html

P.S. : Using **Hackintosh** you might have issues like Audio input disabled, USB disabled etc. but for developing it would serve your purpose.**(To be honest, personally I don't recommend this way. Go for it only if you do not have any option.)**

Comment: Running OS X on non-Apple hardware is a violation of Apple's license agreement. http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/107376/124284 So be aware you are doing something Apple doesn't approve of, and won't support.

Comment: I would like to point out that the exact wording is "one (1) copy of the Apple Software directly on each Apple-branded computer". If you buy a copy of OS X, they helpfully include a couple of Apple stickers in the box. It's easy to comply on any hardware.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use Windows - then [MonoTouch](http://xamarin.com/monotouch) lets you write cross platform Android / iOS apps with C# and .Net.

Comment: Nice. That is something informative.

Comment: Does it have limitations like Phonegap??

Comment: I don't know. I haven't used PhoneGap or MonoTouch. I was just pointing out this option for those with .Net knowledge.

Comment: In short, you still need a Mac to test and deploy the app, even with MonoTouch. See the FAQ: http://support.xamarin.com/customer/portal/articles/136154-do-i-need-a-mac-to-use-monotouch-

Answer (score 1):

You can use [PhoneGap](http://www.phonegap.com) platform. It will run in windows platform.

Comment: Ya. I know [that](http://phonegap.com/start/). But where to write the Code. I have written the application for android load inside the activity. But I don't have the environment for Iphone. For Android .apk file generate and for Iphone .app file generate from where I got that.

Comment: It will, but for iOS development, they still require a "Intel-based computer with Mac OS X Lion (10.7)". http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.9.0/guide_getting-started_ios_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20iOS

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can, but this may include porting the frameworks to another system, including the compiler and the simulator.

There may be some project which already do part of that, but I don't remember the names.

You can also see for other mutli-platform framework which can help you create simple application using html / js.

Answer (score 0):

I actually use a Mac and XCode. However I once tried with Flash that can also be exported to an IPA file runnable on IOS. The problem is that anything runs very very slow so if your application needs dynamic contents it would be a problem.