# Is is possible to run xcode on microsoft windows

Tags: ios, xcode, windows-7, virtualization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iPhone development on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/113547/iphone-development-on-windows)

Obviously i don't have a Mac machine. But i want do develop iOS apps on my windows OS. Also my pc doesn't support virtualization.
Is there any possible way of running xcode on windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. There is no supported or legal way to do so. You'll need to buy a Mac laptop or desktop for iOS development.

The development tools for Windows Phone are free (and Android as well) and both work on Windows. :)

Answer (score 1):

Sorry but [Xcode](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/) is just for Mac. And you are not allowed to virtualize Mac OS X on a Windows computer, it that was what you thought about.

The thing you can do is programming web applications for iPhone, that can be used in Safari. You have a lot of JS functions, JS API, to work with and you can develop it on Windows.

Comment: Thanks for replying, Actually Software like [Vmware](http://www.vmware.com/products/workstation/overview.html)can do this but to only for those windows machines  which support Virtualization. My pc doesn't support that

Comment: But you are not allowed to, according to the Max OS X license

Comment: Regardless of license, I gave up trying different torrent downloads of OS X images trying to get them to run in VMWare....  Looks like you have to buy a MAC.

Comment: Okay why the down vote? What is wrong please tell or edit!

Comment: Who cares about the Mac licence heh. It's not against the law running your own software on your own hardware.