# Can we develop an IOS app with out MAC OS?

Tags: macos, ios5

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do you need Mac os x to develop IPhone apps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9570486/do-you-need-mac-os-x-to-develop-iphone-apps)

I am new to MAC OS Environment. I want to learn, How to develop an apps using iOS SDK.

is it possible to implement iOS apps with out MAC-OS environment?

Could please you help out me on this..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Do you need Mac os x to develop IPhone apps?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9570486/do-you-need-mac-os-x-to-develop-iphone-apps) and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/113547/iphone-development-on-windows?lq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently Apple only allows you to develop apps in the OSX system.

You could try running a virtual machine if hardware is a problem, however that is a challenge in itself.

Actually:

Having done more research, there are ways to use Windows to write iOS apps: http://maniacdev.com/2010/01/iphone-development-windows-options-available/

Answer (score 0):

yes you can.
you have to install VMware or any virtual machines into your system.
works well if you are using windows, with processor above 4GHz