# Developing tweaks for iPhone in Windows

Tags: iphone, ios, pyobjc

I have searched all night and haven't found anything that I can use on this subject.

I want to develop something for my iPhone.  My only requirements are having this app always run in the background, and access the Location Services API on the iPhone.  I don't need to make a GUI or anything like that.

What tools do I need to develop this on a Windows machine, and do I need to know Objective-C to code it?  Can I use PyObjC on Windows to develop this?  Once developed, what do I need to do/install on my iPhone to use it?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Did you search anything before asking question??

Comment: I said in the question, I searched all night.  Its hard to get clear answers, especially when you're inexperienced.

Comment: Did not you read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/113547/iphone-development-on-windows

Comment: you can, if your really determined and have hardware that can cope, install OSX on a windows machine. I don't know how to do it but I've seen it done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could [Jailbreak](http://jailbrea.kr) your iOS device, install [OpenSSH](http://www.iclarified.com/entry/index.php?enid=5637), and then install [Theos](http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/Theos/Getting_Started#On_iOS) on it. Once you've done that, you can start developing on your iOS device. SSH into your iOS device with [Putty](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/) and build your app/tweak. You can join `irc.saurik.net #theos` for more questions. Please have a basic understanding of objective-c before developing anything.

Comment: You're welcome. I have some tweak examples on http://github.com/evilpenguin... Enjoy mate.

Answer (score 0):

There's no ***official*** way to develop native apps for iOS without having the access to an Intel based Mac. There are development environments that run on Windows, but to *get it onto the actual phone or App Store*, you'll need to use tools that aren't available on Windows.

Of course there *are* ways if you're determined, but since I don't want to recommend anything I've never tested, I'll just point to [Google](https://www.google.com/webhp?q=developing+ios+apps+windows&output=search) which has plenty of information on hacks.