# Making iOS Applications on Windows using virtual machine

Tags: ios, virtual-machine

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iPhone development on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/113547/iphone-development-on-windows)

So I'm trying to find a way to make iOS apps on PC. I don't have money to buy Mac so that's not an option. 
I was thinking of installing Mac OSX on Windows using Virtual Machine. I know that Apple won't accept my App if it's not compiled on Mac. But if I give the code to someone who has Mac just to compile it, will they accept it then?
And also, can you give me some tips on making iOS Apps using windows (disadvantages, etc).

Comment: This question has been answered many times before. Please use the search function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will be in violation of the OSX license if you run it inside windows or on any hardware not made by Apple.  While many people get away with this, I wouldn't do this for the purposes of developing software.  If you are wanting to write iOS applications, follow the rules like everyone else and buy a Mac.