# is it possible to install xcode in windows 7 machine?

Tags: xcode, windows

I have one question regarding running XCode in Windows OS

is it possible to install xcode in windows 7 machine?

Comment: Sure. Setup a mac VM and install it on that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are my options for iOS app development on windows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10237337/what-are-my-options-for-ios-app-development-on-windows)

Comment: I believe this duplicates this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2065343/why-isnt-there-xcode-for-windows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not in Apple's interests to let you do that, so they don't make it easy...you could probably use a VM or Hackintosh (I've known devs who used a hackintosh for a while).

Answer (score -1):

Use a Virtual Machine (VirtualBox for example) to run OSX in Windows.

Comment: Why is this being voted down?