# How can I develop iOS applications on a Windows Platform?

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, sdk

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iPhone development on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/113547/iphone-development-on-windows)

Xcode 4 only works on Mac and I am getting project requests for iOS and I need to develop iOS applications without uying a Mac. I have a Windows PC. Is there an IDE which works well with iOS SDK or is developing C++ code which uses iOS SDK libraries the only choice?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/113547/iphone-development-on-windows

Comment: Please note that that very popular, but closed, question has many good answers which were valid when given in 2008-2009. Times have changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One newer solution which is open source is called **MonoCross**.
Here's a link to [their site](http://www.monocross.net/), and here's the [Google code site](https://code.google.com/p/monocross/).
From their site:

> Monocross is an open source cross-platform mobile framework using C#
> .NET and the Mono framework. Monocross lets you create beautiful
> applications on iPads, iPhones, Android devices, Windows Phone 7, and
> Webkit enabled phones.

It uses C#. No C++ required.

Edit: MonoCross uses MonoTouch.

Answer (score 1):

If you are familiar with C#, consider [monotouch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/monotouch). You will need a mac to register the app in any case.

Answer (score 0):

In your situation, if you have no  Mac around, it will be better and easier to use VirtualBox (or VMware) and install MacOS there. And to develop inside the VB.

Comment: ... which is not officialy supported and allowed by apple!

Comment: I was informed you can develop, but you can't upload your app from a VM.

Comment: @JonasSchnelli , of course:) Another cheap way is to use hackintosh, but it's also illegal