# iPhone application development training using PC's

Tags: xcode, cross-platform

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iPhone development on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/113547/iphone-development-on-windows)

We would like to conduct iPhone application development training for students. However, it is very expensive to have a mac machine for all. We would like to setup a virtual environment on the PC to install and run mac OS so that development tools like XCode can run and basics of iPhone application development can be taught. We will we will invest in a couple of macs, iPhones and iPads so that students who want to try out their exercises on the real machine and deploy to real devices.

I have heard that this kind of a development setup is possible, but am not sure how and so would like to know if anyone has setup such an environment, how to do about doing it.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible unless you build a so called "Hackintosh" (installing OSX on a non-mac computer) with [this for example](http://www.osx86.net/) But I doubt that's a solution for an official "organization", and if you want the apps to be deployed to the app store, you **must** have a mac

Comment: then please explain how to do it on windows..?

Comment: It is possible for Xcode to run on a virtual Mac on a PC running VMWare. I just think for the askers situation this wouldn't be a very effective solution.

Comment: and how easy is it do get this setup running?

Comment: It's actually pretty cut and dry, Install VMWare and follow its on-screen guides to install OS X(with your own Mac install file of course). You will then be running OS X inside a bottle as an application within Windows. (both OS's share system resources) I have never done this for Xcode use but you should be able to run Xcode and the Simulator no problem, however it is **VERY** unlikely that it is even possible to use a VM bottled copy of OS X to deploy to a real device.

Comment: ok, but the last part is for sure^^

Comment: @MJB 99% sure, if you find a way I'd be very interested to hear it. If this is something you're interested in doing I wouldn't advise it, and provided the PC has the right hardware, a hackintosh setup may be a better long term solution. However, this solution will be MUCH more difficult to properly achieve. (keep in mind this will severely violate the OS X EULA)

Comment: a hackintosh is pretty straight forward to build, you even get SnowLeopard running on an AMD easily. It has some problems, but Xcode runs without problems. I've never seen an app programmed on a hackintosh on a real device though

Answer (score 1):

i Don't know about the basic xcode on PC, but for your submission to appsotre, you need MAC OSX, if you don't have a mac machine or mac book, try installing mac osx using VMWare, but your CPU should have a suport of Intel Virtualization technology which almost all new CPU has especially core series.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite easy.  Buy OS X Lion (which will run in a virtual machine) using family licenses (5 machines per copy), install VirtualBox (it's free) and away you go.

That would be the least expensive route for sandbox learning on a budget.