# How to build native apps for iPhone using Windows?

Tags: iphone, ios

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iPhone development on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/113547/iphone-development-on-windows)

I want to build apps for the iPhone but i can't find a right program. 
I don't have a mac, so xcode isn't possible. I used MobiOne, but i had to pay, and i prefer a program that's completely free.
I want to ask if some of you know a program to build native iPhone apps thats compatible with windows and is completely free.

Yours,
Gromdroid

Comment: see my answer here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10786966/is-there-a-free-iphone-compiler-and-emulator/10786999#10786999

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need a Mac computer with an Intel CPU and MacOS X 10.6+, and a copy of the Xcode software (it's free) to build apps for iPhone. That's the Apple policy. They just don't license the build toolchain to anyone. Even with third party iOS-compatible SDKs like Mono or PhoneGap you have to produce the final build on Xcode.

A Hackintosh or MacOS X under VMWare is probably your best bet, short of buying the cheapest Mac Mini you can find.

To upload your apps to the App Store or to live devices (as opposed to the emulator) you'll have to pay, too. $100/year for a basic account.

EDIT: IIRC, in the latest policy, you **can** run and debug on devices without a paid developer account. To upload to the App Store, an account is still required.

Comment: As a side note, if all you need to do is code, then you can buy slightly older used macs very cheap (few hundred bucks). Look around your local classifieds.

Comment: I have upvoted this answer as it explains the requirements and the process, however, I feel it is worth noting that you will need an Apple computer with an Intel processor and at least Mac OS X 10.6 Snow Leopard to be able to install the iOS SDK and develop apps for iPhones, iPods and iPads.

Comment: @Seva Alekseyev Thank for your information. My school asked me if i would help them with building apps. So they don't have to come in the app store, do you know some other free software to build the app and just get an ipa without mac if i don't want to upload it to app store?

Comment: The Mac+Xcode requirement is specifically for building software, not for the App Store. Even without App Store you need a Mac, or a passable substitute - see my answer.

Comment: @SevaAlekseyev Thanks for all the information.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't be of any more help, but that's Apple for you.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know much about this, from my limited knowledge,you can Use **phone gap** for application development. It's free and you can develop applications for I-phone,android,windows mobile,black berry etc using this sdk.
**Titanium sdk** is another one.

But you need to create IPA on XCode for installing it on Apple devices (Iphone,Ipad etc).

It's better if you install Mac OS on your windows machine using Virtual box ([Virtual box](https://www.virtualbox.org/)).
Please check the sdk links.
 [Phone gap](http://phonegap.com/)
 [Titanium](http://www.appcelerator.com/)

Answer (score 0):

if you're good in java/lwuit programming you can also check Codename One http://codenameone.com
you use their designer and framework, and you publish to iphone, android, j2me etc..
you'll still need development certificates.