# How to develop an iPhone app on Windows AMD

Tags: iphone, windows, macos

I've googled and called like 15 computer services stores but didn't find help. I need to develop an iPhone app but I don't have a Mac. I've learned that the only way it's possible to install a virtual Mac on Windows is you need Intel, not AMD like I have. Maybe somebody encountered this issue and can help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPhone development on Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/113547/iphone-development-on-windows)

Comment: 1) Make a Hackintosh
2) Get Xcode
Not that we endorse that

Answer (score 1):

Here is a post on how to install snow leopard http://www.sysprobs.com/mac-snow-leopard-amd-pc-vmware-image you can check this too http://asendure.wordpress.com/2006/10/01/osx86-how-to-install-mac-os-x-on-vmware-server-amd-64/

Answer (score 0):

Wow, that's asking for trouble. Apple is not that big on that and your going to be swimming upstream all the way.

Im going to go out on a limb here and say that if you really need to develop an iPhone App you'll have a lot fewer headaches if you simply get a mac mini. They don't cost that much.

It is not so easy to get OSX running in a VM on something other than OSX. The only legally sanctioned things is that you can run OTHER versions of OSX in a VM ON OSX (using Fusion). You should follow all the threads on that comment to your original post.. re being a possible duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just develop,or study iOS, you can use VMWare, but if you want to submit your app in App Store, I don't know if its possible. Maybe you just really need to buy a 2nd hand Mac Mini. But in my laptop I use VMWare just to try it, but I never did try developing my app in it. Because its kinda slow, I think you need a lot of Ram to run it flawlessly in VMWare. Or try dual boot like Hackintosh but Its not advisable. I dunno, its your call, but I suggest buying a 2nd hand Mac Mini if you want to pursue your career on it. :)