# building iphone apps on windows with another way without flash

Tags: iphone, ios

I want another way to building  iphone apps on windows  without flash cs5

Reason not to use Flash ( Despite I'm pro on Actionscript ) :

Flash only for :

```
iPod touch (3rd generation) 32 GB and 64 GB model, iPod touch 4, iPhone 3GS, iPhone 4, iPad, iPad 2, iPad3
iOS 4.2 or later
```

**EDIT 1**

HTML5 apps : i want to know if this can be published as an app without the browser stuff as in the address bar, etc

Comment: I'm a little lost here... To clarify, you're looking for a method to develop iOS applications using Windows as your Dev platform, right?

Comment: There are already lots of questions about developing iOS apps on Windows. e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11361269/develop-iphone-application-in-windows http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11284432/how-to-develop-an-iphone-app-on-windows-amd

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I develop for iPhone using a Windows development machine?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22358/how-can-i-develop-for-iphone-using-a-windows-development-machine)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need any features of the native-API, then you could just build the app using HTML5 and JavaScript?

Comment: I think using HTML5 I only make a web site not .ipa file ;)

Comment: You don't need .ipa files for apps - see http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#referencelibrary/GettingStarted/GS_iPhoneWebApp/_index.html

Answer (score 0):

Since you are asking an alternative for flash, I hope you are into game development.

Irrlicht is a free open source game engine .. You can give it a try

Works with Microsoft VisualStudio, Metrowerks Codewarrior, Bloodshed Dev-C++, Code::Blocks, XCode, and gcc 3.x-4.x.

http://irrlicht.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Does this let you build an iOS app anything other than a Mac?

Comment: Yes . You can use Microsoft VisualStudio on windows to build ios apps (games).  and programming language for irrlicht is c++

Comment: It looks more like irrlicht is a games engine. You can add it to your Xcode project to build for iOS apps, but you can't build iOS apps on Visual Studio, so this is clearly wrong. You still need Xcode (which only runs on OS X) to build for iOS using this engine.

Answer (score -1):

You could try phonegap.  It is html/css/javascript but you are building an actual app for the appstore and not just a website for use by the iphone browser.

http://phonegap.com

edit again: I knew there was another one I was thinking of - I found it
http://www.genuitec.com/mobile/index.html
This one does let you build only on windows and submit to app store etc

edit: sorry I guess actually this would not help as it is alternative to using objective-c or flash but it does still require a mac and would not work with just windows