# Iphone/Ipad apps development on a normal PC with mac OS

Tags: iphone, xcode, macos, ipad

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iPhone development on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/113547/iphone-development-on-windows)

I've got a standard windows machine, if I duel boot it with mac OS Lion or whatever is newest. Will I be able to develop apps and fully use the enviorments if I dont use an original mac machine ?

Comment: (a) it won't be legal and (b) you may have problems signing your apps

Comment: @PaulR (a)Agree (b)Won't have any issue with that.

Comment: oh man, what is up with development for apple products :(

Comment: Legal in what terms ? I only want the apps for the company it self not app store?

Comment: @user1509396 It is illegal to use Mac OS on a non-apple hardware.

Comment: May be you could get a mac mini??

Comment: will a mac mini be sufficient ? or should I got pro style ?

Comment: Mac mini's are more than sufficient. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

I think there is no chance to install Mac OS on a non-Mac Hardware except Mac OS 10.7+. Mac OS 10.7+ is runnable in Virtual Machines. But it is very slow and often crashes. So absolutely no environment to develop (although Xcode would run in the VM).

My tip: Buy a second-hand MacBook.

Comment: Are you suggesting that it can't be done or it is illegal?

Comment: I don't know if it's legal or illegal. Read the TOS.

Comment: Practically it is possible to install OSX in a non-apple hardware, few tweaks are required. But yes, it is illegal. ;)

Comment: afaik. It is illegal if you don't have a license Key for the OS