# Does Visual Studio 2010 support iPhone Development?

Tags: iphone, visual-studio

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I develop for iPhone using a Windows development machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22358/how-can-i-develop-for-iphone-using-a-windows-development-machine)

Does Visual Studio 2010 support iPhone Development?

Comment: perhaps you misheard the llvm support announcement from WWDC because llvm has msil compatibility?

Comment: You can develop hybrid HTML5 apps in Visual Studio with PhoneGap. You'll need a cloud build service like the [Nomad Visual Studio extension](http://www.vsnomad.com/) to completely remove the need for a mac.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Xcode](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/) must be used to develop for the iPhone. It is the only platform for which the iPhone SDK is available.

Comment: That was the library grouping I couldn't remember.  Although some basic objective c via gcc could be done in windows but it would be VERY basic

Comment: I selected you as the corerct answer, though not first, you offered the most over-all informative info. Thanks.

Comment: Nice to see someone marked the answer that wasn't first.  Although my forgetting it was called XCode probably cost me a few points :(

Comment: FYI: I always vote up all responses, provided that they offer somet useful info that was not previously stated, yours included.

Comment: XCode isnt a library grouping, but a complete IDE.  The libraries necessary are Cocoa Touch

Comment: ** Actually, it's “Xcode”, not “XCode”.

Answer (score 13):

I believe you can use Mono to develop for the iPhone. You can read more about this here www.mono-project.com/Mono:Iphone

This requires Static compilation, and I've heard the process is pretty difficult at this point.  Here is an article that provides some details http://arstechnica.com/open-source/news/2009/01/open-source-mono-framework-brings-c-to-iphone-and-wii.ars

If you are beginning iPhone development similar to myself I'd suggest sticking with XCode and the Apple tools.  Although they offer a different developer experience then we are used to from Microsoft tools, they seem to have a good helpful community around them.

Update: Mono Touch now allows you to do development using MonoDevelop and statically compile for the iPhone.  Here is the link with more info http://monotouch.net/

Comment: And if you're really keen on using Visual Studio, then the use of Mono from within Visual Studio is on its way: Mono tools for Visual Studio (see http://www.mono-project.com/news/archive/2009/Jun-08.html) is undergoing a (closed) preview

Answer (score 6):

According to my knowlage, the iPhone SDK must be run on **Mac OS** system, so I dont think that
you will be able to develop using VS.

Answer (score 5):

Okay, I know this post is old, but I feel as though I need to correct some things. First of all, it is entirely possible to develop for iPhone using Visual Studio 2010. The steps required to do so are long and complicated, but basically involve the following

(note: these are rough steps as I don't recall the exact commands I used to invoke these things, but I have managed to get a working ARM CortexA8 and A9 GCC compiler successfully running with the latest iOS Dev SDK on Win 7 x64 and using Visual Studio 2010)

1. Get Cygwin and make sure you grab the GCC compiler collection.
2. Get LLVM and the GCC front-end(not sure if Clang works as I haven't tried it)
3. Get ODCCTools.
4. Download the latest Xcode(from a torrent if you're on a PC). Note: Due to the fact that Xcode and the iOS SDK use various open source copyleft packages, Apple *has* to release the SDK to the general public for free. However, as of iOS 5, they've decided to make it so that only people using the App Store on a Mac can download it. I have attempted to contact Apple to see if they plan on releasing the various packages openly, but I haven't heard a response.
5. Compile LLVM
6. Compile ODCCTools. Note: ODCCTools requires some modifications in order for it to work with the latest LLVM GCC Front-end. I've contacted the current owner and he basically told me he is no longer supporting it.
7. Using the assembler and linker you just compiled from ODCCTools, recompile the GCC front-end.

At this point, you'll have a working compiler for the iOS platform using all the latest and greatest from the LLVM guys and the fixes and improvements that have been made to GCC(C++0x anyone?). Or, if you're really lazy and you don't want to go through all this hassle, you can use the compiler that is already generated from [iphone-devtools](http://code.google.com/p/iphone-dev/). However, doing this will only give you a compiler that doesn't support the CortexA8 or A9 instruction set which means that your application will run a little slower, plus the are using an older version of GCC which means all the fixes and improvements that have been made in the last 4 years will be ignored.

All you need to do now is configure visual studio.

There are a few ways to configure visual studio to accept the new compiler you just made(or downloaded). I opted to use a python script which then generates makefiles and the various project/solution files, but you may want to choose something a little less heavyweight.

At this point, you should be able to compile for iphone, but in order to run on the iphone you need to jailbreak your phone. Jailbreaking is legal, but it does void your warranty. Once jailbroken, then you can use SSH to upload your executable to the phone and then you're done.

If you want to publish your app on the App Store, you'll still need to get a developer certificate and go through the publishing process outlined by Apple. At this point, you will need a Mac. If all you want to do is develop for the iPhone, then this will allow you to do so, but if you want to publish to the App Store, you will need a Mac.

The reason I went through the pain of doing all of this is because I have a very complicated setup for my continuous integration. I compile for 8 different target machines, 5 different configurations, and deploy and run massive amounts of unit tests. I didn't want to have to setup a different Mac box just to handle the iOS platform when I knew that I could just set it all up to run on one machine. Ultimately, trying to do iOS programming on a Win7 machine if iOS is your target platform is definitely not worth the hassle for ordinary developers.

Comment: Great, share all this stuff per-configured would be nice.

Comment: Duplicate or not, I just bookmarked this because of this information.

Answer (score 4):

Yes it is possible go to this link: http://www.pmbaty.com/iosbuildenv/

Comment: Hi. While the answer is technically correct, you should strive to put more text into the answer so that it would have relevance even if the site you're linking to is offline at the moment where someone stumbles upon it.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think visual studio 2010 is supporting native iOS app development. But it is possible to write applications for ios using visual studio 2010.
As far as I am concerned, microsoft is trying to make it possible. According to my experiences of developing applications for iOS, I used mac air book,  Xcode & iOS sdk for building iOS apps. The main language for building native iOS apps is objective c and the framework is cocoa touch. There is no support for these technolOgies in visual studio and .NET framework, although mono develop is trying a lot
iOS is the most advanced OS for mobile devices which is to us from Apple. According to their requirements for developing iOS apps you have to use:

1. Intel based mac OSX.
2. Ios sdk
3. Xcode or Dashcode.

All these are available on only apple mac. So no luck for .NET players. But you can pure c to develop ios apps on widows. Just google it.

I think it made you clear of the ios app developing processes, and it's requirement.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Due to the libraries used - I'm fairly sure you need to run this on a Mac OS System.  You can do some basic gcc compiling using cygwin if you wanted to - but other than that I would think you'll need Mac OS

It's why most of us are stuck buying a Mac Mini - getting a putty knife and adding more RAM and then struggling to get our old LCD monitors to work

Answer (score 1):

Apple supported development from within Visual Studio would be really great!
However, as far as i know Apple has absolutely no intention to release such a thing. Even the usage agreement that all iOS developers have to agree to disallows usage of the SDK on 'non-Apple branded computers'. 
In my humble opinion, this is really a bad thing because it forces multi-platform applications to be developed on multiple operating systems.

Because of this, i have started implementing a Visual Studio 2010 package that allows for iOS development from within the IDE. To workaround the SDK agreement compilation is executed on a iOS powered device.

Development progress (including screenshots) can be folowed on:

http://www.petervrenken.nl/visual%20studio

Greetings,

Peter Vrenken

Answer (score 0):

I think it's possible to identify a device/browser on the server side. Therefore, it should be possible to develop server-sided applications that behave like an iPhone app but run in the iPhone's Safari browser.
I could very well imagine that with VS2010 the device support is significant for the iPhone in the way that it comes with a special JavaScript Library that your Safari implicitly downloads the first time.
The Commerce Server appears to have a support like this already - good news for everybody who is not in love with Objective-C or maybe wants to minimize effort ind iPhone development 
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=2df25ab7-f38d-439e-9391-ef8f025e8064&displaylang=en