# How to build iphone apps using .Net on windows?

Tags: c#, .net, iphone, windows

Are there any tools (emulators, IDE) which can help you develop iphone apps using .Net on windows and then publish to iTunes?

Comment: Shouldn't this be on stackoverflow.com?

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22358/how-can-i-develop-for-iphone-using-a-windows-development-machine

Comment: it is similar but I am looking specifically for .Net tools

Answer (score 7):

[Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Mono:Iphone) are working on porting their .Net runtime to the iPhone, which will be available for testing next month.

[Unity](http://unity3d.com/unity/features/iphone-publishing) is a game development platform for the iPhone that uses C# and .Net.

Comment: System Requirements for Unity iPhone Authoring

    * An Intel-based Mac
    * Mac OS X "Leopard" 10.5.4 or later
    * Using Occlusion Culling requires NVIDIA or ATI graphics card
    * The rest only depends on the complexity of your projects!

Comment: Mono on iPhone was actually discussed in SO Podcast #61 (see the fifth bullet point): http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/podcast-61

Comment: MonoTouch is not available to develop C# apps for the iPhone.

Answer (score 2):

Not only can you not use .Net on an iPhone, you also need an Intel Mac to do development. Apple is keeping it a very closed environment, and because they control everything from the hardware to the OS to the distribution channels, you really don't have any other choice than to play by their rules.

Answer (score 0):

You can't, especially if you want to publish to iTunes.  The iPhone only runs Objective-C.

Answer (score 0):

None that are viable at this point.